# Migration error at startup for Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, macos, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda

Installed Anaconda3 (Anaconda Navigator 1.8.7) for Mac OS X (10.13.5) as part of a JuliaPro (0.6.3) install. Every time I try to launch Jupyter Notebook (Terminal or Navigator GUI), I get this:

> Prestbury:~ me$ jupyter notebook Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in 
>       sys.exit(main())   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py",
>   line 266, in launch_instance
>       return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)   File
>   "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",
>   line 657, in launch_instance
>       app.initialize(argv)   File "", line 2, in initialize   File
>   "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",
>   line 87, in catch_config_error
>       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line
>   1501, in initialize
>       super(NotebookApp, self).initialize(argv)   File "", line 2, in initialize   File
>   "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",
>   line 87, in catch_config_error
>       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py",
>   line 242, in initialize
>       self.migrate_config()   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py",
>   line 168, in migrate_config
>       migrate()   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/migrate.py", line
>   247, in migrate
>       with open(os.path.join(env['jupyter_config'], 'migrated'), 'w') as f: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   '/Users/me/.jupyter/migrated'

I have completely removed Anaconda3 and performed a fresh install after also installing nodejs. The problem persists. Any recommendation please?

Comment: It seems that Anaconda3 is not removed yet: the callstack mentions lines inside files under `/anaconda3`.

Comment: This is the callstack after doing a clean re-install of Anaconda3. It is expected. Thanks!